# How do I improve regex to eliminate unnecessary method chaining?

Tags: ruby, regex, methods, refactoring

This functional method takes a number and returns the same value separated with commas, as is the common convention in the US.

The only way I could get it to work with regex was to reverse the string before and after the expression.  Is there a regex that can help me eliminate the need to call String#reverse twice for method functionality?

```
def separate_comma(number)
  raise "You must enter a number." if number.is_a?(Numeric) == false
  number.to_s.reverse.gsub(/(\d{3})(?=\d{1,3})/, "\\1,").reverse
end
```

Comment: Give the input and expected output also

Comment: You can use this regex instead: `/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/` (taken from [ActiveSupport::NumberHelper::NumberToDelimitedConverter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/number_helper/number_to_delimited_converter.rb))

Comment: @ZachKemp The regex breaks down if the number has more than 3 decimal places.  May not be an issue for OP though.  `"1234.5678".gsub(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/, "\\1,") => "1,234.5,678"`

Comment: True. `ActiveSupport` splits the number on the separator first before `gsub` is called.

Comment: It is not common to insert commas for fractional numbers.

Comment: Jay, for stylistic reasons (only), consider `raise "You must enter a number." unless number.is_a?(Numeric)`.

Comment: `3.2.is_a? Numeric => true`.  Do you mean `is_a? Fixnum`?  Is so, please edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"1234556".gsub(/\d(?=\d{3}+\b)/,'\\0,')
# => "1,234,556"
```

This doesn't handle long fractional values, but this wasn't a concern for the OP's regex either.

Answer (score 1):

Other libraries have already solved this problem - `ActiveSupport` for one.

```
require "active_support/number_helper"
ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_delimited(1234567890)
#=> "1,234,567,890"
```

You can even change the delimiter if you wish:

```
ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_delimited(1234567890, delimiter: "|")
#=> "1|234|567|890"
```

Answer (score 0):

The established way to do it is:

```
string.gsub(/(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+\z)/, ",")
```

If you want to do it with floats:

```
string.gsub(/(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+[.\z])/, ",")
```

Comment: This is functional for an integer, but for any float, like a currency, it does not.