# Prawn PDF number_with_delimiter number_to_currency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I add a ',' in between large numbers, so that `1000` shows as `1,000`? I'm using Prawn to generate pdfs

```
undefined method `number_to_currency' for
```

Is what I get when I use number_to_currency, and

```
undefined method `number_with_delimiter' for
```

when I use number_with_delimiter

Comment: Please state along with your question what you have tried so far.
Not enough meat to chew on ;)

Comment: Both number_to_currency and number_with_delimiter, and I get "undefined method `number_to_currency' for"

Comment: Where are you using number_with_delimiter. Inside view ?

Comment: Also cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892046.